# Why do the Microsoft guidelines for F# not recommend returning a tuple from code that will be used by C#?

Tags: c#, f#

According to the F# guidelines, tuples as a return type from F# are not recommended for code that will be consumed from C#.

[Avoid using tuples as return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#avoid-using-tuples-as-return-values).

There seems to be good compatibility for tuples between the two languages. Especially in the newer versions. So, I don't quite understand this recommendation. I'm planning to return a struct instead to avoid whatever the harm is that these guidelines must have in mind.

The explanation they give is vague.

> they will most often not provide the ideal and expected API for .NET developers.

What does this mean exactly? What pitfalls can I expect to run into if I ignore this and return tuples anyway?

Comment: Do the f# tuple field names pass through to C# [tuple field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names), or does the C# developer have to use `Item1`, `Item2` and so on?  To get it to work right, I believe the f# compiler would need to apply the [`TupleElementNamesAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.tupleelementnamesattribute?view=net-7.0) to the f# function when compiling.

Comment: This seems relevant: [Interoperation with C# Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/tuples#interoperation-with-c-tuples): *Tuples in C# are structs, and are equivalent to struct tuples in F#. If you need to interoperate with C#, you must use struct tuples.*

Comment: Oh yeah. I didn't think about the names at all. I'll need to dig into that a bit. I was thinking more about destructuring the tuple into a couple of variables to get the parts out.

Comment: Excellent point about the F# struct tuple type mapping to C#. I'll definitely use those on the F# side if I end up going with tuples.

Comment: I think it would be more precise to say tuples in F# default to (one of) the reference type `Tuple<>` while tuples in (recent) C# are by default `ValueTuple<>` which are `struct`s (hence values). You can use `Tuple<>` in C# but it is (mostly) deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the direct answer to your question is that most C# and .NET API's don't return tuples. Originally, this was because older versions of C# didn't support tuples, but now it is an established pattern, for better or worse. The F# guideline simply follows the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

For example, consider [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-7.0):

```
public bool TryGetValue (TKey key, out TValue value);
```

F# automatically converts this to `TKey -> (bool * TValue)`, but the fact remains that the tuple return type is not expected in C#.

So, if you're the consumer of the API, then of course you should define it the way you want now. But if this is a public API that will be consumed by typical C# developers, I would strongly consider following the established pattern, even if it is uglier.

That said, tuple return types might (and probably should) become more common in C# and .NET over time. If so, I expect the F# design guideline will eventually be updated as well.

Comment: I think I would also mention that tuples in F# default to reference type `Tuple<>` which is essentially deprecated in C# which uses `ValueTuple` as its default, equivalent to the F# `struct` tuples.